# New top nav loses global inbox at certain sizes in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

On Stack Overflow, the [new top navigation bar](/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) seems to be designed exclusively for users who run their browser maximized.  I miss inbox notifications all the time now because I need room on my screen for other things too, thank you very much.

[image: Screen shot with prominent freehand circle]

The "Search ..." text field's width seems completely excessive here.  Could the design be refactored to move it to the right of the supercollider menu, or make it *much* smaller (perhaps only expand it when you type something into it, i.e. for me practically never?)

By playing around with resizing my browser window (which I rarely do otherwise) I notice that window widths around 900 pixels are particularly problematic -- when you resize below a certain width, features are dropped from the nav bar successively, but at this particular size, the Search field is resized back to a larger size, and thus it pushes out the supercollider partially or completely.  I would call this a bug in the resizing logic -- it seems the intent is to shrink the search field to accommodate other features, but it breaks at this point.

On Meta, I can see the supercollider and hamburger menu just fine, for the record -- we don't have Documentation here, so the (not really) tabs take up much less space.

My current browser is Chrome on macOS Yosemite.  Quick experimentation with Safari seems to indicate that resizing works better there.

Comment: Interesting that the "Users" link is one of the stickier parts of the UI, remaining around at even the narrowest of window sizes. I wonder how much use it actually receives. I know, personally, I've never had occasion to search for an individual user through that interface, though perhaps I'm simply missing some tremendous benefit to having it always available that is obvious to everyone else.

Comment: I am on Firefox on 1280x768, mostly stackoverflow. The unsticky top bar is even worse. The hamburger etc start disappearing offscreen on the right with zoom or resize. My rep & badges disappear... but reappear when I get rep. You also have two columns of content below the bar. Why are these all not properly sized to a window?

Comment: That's a little strange; for me (Chrome + Windows 10) the search bar shrinks with the screen size and when I click into it all the tabs are hidden and I can only see the SO logo to the left of it.  I can see my rep, inbox, achievements, review queue, etc. all the way down to 650px width.

Comment: Maybe sticky vs. non-sticky is a factor here as well?  I switched to non-sticky almost immediately when it was made available as an option.

Comment: This should be improved in one of coming builds.

Comment: @Pawel can you verify https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345143/adapt-new-site-layout-for-half-width-1080p is about the same issue?

Comment: @Stijn that other issue seems to by _slightly_ different, but looks like my update will also fix the other issue

Comment: Confirm fixed.  @Paweł do you want to post an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) I've slightly improved "responsivness" for header so now searchbar will decrease its width as much as it can to keep icons visible as long as possible.

Comment: Still not particularly happy that notifications are now in the upper right corner -- still missing them.  But that's outside the scope of this particular problem.  Thanks for the fix.