# Adapt new site layout for half-width 1080p

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is a problem with the new site layout for half-width 1080p screens, i.e. two windows side-by-side. The notification and reputation change badges are juuuust off screen now, and you see just enough of the notification icon to think that there is no badge there.

[image]

[image]

The old site design wasn't adapted for half-width 1080p screens either, but it only cut off the search bar and half the text from network questions and the likes, so it wasn't really a big problem.

[image]

Could you please reduce the size of the search bar for small screens so that the icons for notification, reputation and site switcher fit on screen? The search bar still expands on focus, and it takes up more than a third of the screen width, so I don't think people will miss it even if you make it a little bit smaller.

Having the blog/featured/hot/tags/network questions parts partially off-screen isn't a problem at all for me; just leave it half off-screen like it is (and was before).

Comment: Similar, or duplicate even, to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344733/new-top-nav-loses-global-inbox-at-certain-sizes-in-chrome ?

Comment: @Stijn I think it is and has a recent (as in 40 minutes ago) comment from a dev that a change is due soon (in 6 to 8 builds)

Comment: Can you check whether the changes of today fix the problem you're having, @Filip?

Comment: @Stijn it did :) Well, the site switcher is 50% covered by the scroll bar, but it's definitely good enough!

Comment: I made a user script for a 1080p screen: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknarrow/gedamclmheaaaghbopmamikcgdpibikn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog . The code is also at github if you would rather not run it as an extension.